# How to debug static resource with chrome dev tools?

Tags: lightning-web-components, debugging, chrome

I am using a lightning web component that loads a JavaScript static resource.

I have loaded the static resource with `loadScript`.

How do I find this static resource in chrome dev tools to debug it?

I have already enabled debug mode for my scratch org user.